# How can I determine if a function is being memoized in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, memoization

I've got a Haskell program that is performing non linearly performance wise (worse then `O(n)`).

I'm trying to investigate whether memoization is taking place on a function, can I verify this? I'm familiar with GHC profiling - but I'm not too sure which values I should be looking at?

A work around is too just plug some values and observe the execution time - but it's not ideal.

Comment: https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-14-memoization-in-hasekll.html

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization

Comment: I've read through those, and although they explain the technique and how to, it doesn't touch on actually verifying a function is being memoizated.

Comment: You can read the Core output by GHC (with `ghc -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all`), and look for `let` bindings that should be floated out of their surrounding functions.

Comment: Care to share a code snippet? Or wouldn that be distracting to us? Curious what it is about.

Comment: Use Debug.Trace on things you think might be recomputed, see if they show up multiple times

Comment: Oh and just so you know, there isn't like some flag that ghc ticks to memoize a function like it seems you might be thinking--the sharing semantics are quite predictable.  Use Debug.Trace to develop your intuition.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no automatic memoization in Haskell.

That said there seems to be an optimization in GHC that caches values for parameterless function like the following

```
rightTriangles = [ (a,b,c) | 
    c <- [1..], 
    b <- [1..c], 
    a <- [1..b], 
    a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

If you try out the following in GHCi twice, you'll see that the second call ist much faster:

```
ghci > take 500 rightTriangles
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "parameterless functions" in Haskell. `rightTriangles` is just a list. Laziness means the individual *values* in the list are only computed on demand. When you first call `take 500 rightTriangles`, the first 500 values have to actually be computed (in order to actually display the values). For the second call, those first 500 values are, of course, still in memory.

Comment: yes, if by "parameterless functions" you mean "constant applicative forms" or CAFs.

Comment: yes, I was taking about [CAFs](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form). `ints = from 1  where  from n = n : from (n+1)` is another example for a CAF.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but should still be helpfull, memoization does not seem to make a difference in profiling output in terms of function "entries". Demonstrated with the following basic example:

```
module Main where


fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

fibmemo = (map fib [0 ..] !!)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Begin.."
  print $ fib 10
  -- print $ fibmemo 10
```

With the above code the profiling output is:

```
                                                                             individual      inherited
COST CENTRE  MODULE                SRC                    no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN         MAIN                  <built-in>             119          0    0.0    1.3     0.0  100.0
 CAF         Main                  <entire-module>        237          0    0.0    1.0     0.0    1.2
  main       Main                  Main.hs:(12,1)-(14,16) 238          1    0.0    0.2     0.0    0.2
   fib       Main                  Main.hs:(5,1)-(7,29)   240        177    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF         GHC.Conc.Signal       <entire-module>        230          0    0.0    1.2     0.0    1.2
 CAF         GHC.IO.Encoding       <entire-module>        220          0    0.0    5.4     0.0    5.4
 CAF         GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv <entire-module>        218          0    0.0    0.4     0.0    0.4
 CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.FD      <entire-module>        210          0    0.0   67.7     0.0   67.7
 CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.Text    <entire-module>        208          0    0.0    0.2     0.0    0.2
 main        Main                  Main.hs:(12,1)-(14,16) 239          0    0.0   22.6     0.0   22.6
```

While if we comment out `fib 10` and uncomment the `fibmemo 10` we get:

```
                                                                             individual      inherited
COST CENTRE  MODULE                SRC                    no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN         MAIN                  <built-in>             119          0    0.0    1.2     0.0  100.0
 CAF         Main                  <entire-module>        237          0    0.0    1.0     0.0    2.9
  fibmemo    Main                  Main.hs:9:1-29         240          1    0.0    1.6     0.0    1.6
   fib       Main                  Main.hs:(5,1)-(7,29)   242        177    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main       Main                  Main.hs:(12,1)-(15,20) 238          1    0.0    0.2     0.0    0.2
   fibmemo   Main                  Main.hs:9:1-29         241          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF         GHC.Conc.Signal       <entire-module>        230          0    0.0    1.2     0.0    1.2
 CAF         GHC.IO.Encoding       <entire-module>        220          0    0.0    5.3     0.0    5.3
 CAF         GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv <entire-module>        218          0    0.0    0.4     0.0    0.4
 CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.FD      <entire-module>        210          0    0.0   66.6     0.0   66.6
 CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.Text    <entire-module>        208          0    0.0    0.2     0.0    0.2
 main        Main                  Main.hs:(12,1)-(15,20) 239          0    0.0   22.2     0.0   22.2
```